# Use add operation in two textbox with a specific integer and specific date?

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible or do I need to convert it first? This is my code but the output is coming wrong:

```
TextBox7.Text = TextBox6.Text + time.Text.Substring(4)
```

This will be the sample run:

```
TextBox6.Text = "5.12"
time.Text = "9.51 AM 3/3/2014"
```

This is the result:

```
Textbox7.Text  = "14.63 AM 3/3/2014"
```

Expected Result :

```
Textbox7.Text  = "15.03 AM 3/3/2014"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try Like This

```
 TextBox7.Text = Val(TextBox6.Text) + Val(Strings.Left(time.Text.Trim,4)) & 
 Val(Strings.Right(time.Text.Trim,(time.Text.Trim.Length-4)))
```

**EDIT**

```
 TextBox7.Text = Format(Val(TextBox6.Text) + Val(Strings.Left(time.Text.Trim, 4)), 
 "##.##") & Strings.Right(time.Text.Trim, 12)
```

**EDIT NEW REQ:**

```
 TextBox3.Text = Format(Val(TextBox6.Text) + Val(Strings.Left(time.Text.Trim, 5)), "##.00")

        If Val(TextBox6.Text.Trim.Split(".")(1)) >= 60 Then
            TextBox6.Text = Val(TextBox6.Text.Trim.Split(".")(0)) + 1 & "." & 
            Val(TextBox6.Text.Trim.Split(".")(1) - 60)
        End If

 TextBox7.Text = Format(Val(TextBox6.Text), "##.##") & Strings.Right(time.Text.Trim, 12)
```

**EDIT NEW REQ**

```
  TextBox7.Text = Format(Val(TextBox6.Text) + Val(Strings.Left(time.Text.Trim, 5)),
   "#0.00")

        Dim xDate As Date = Format(CDate(Strings.Right(time.Text.Trim, 12)), "tt
        MM/dd/yyyy")

        If Val(TextBox7.Text.Trim.Split(".")(1)) >= 60 Then
            TextBox7.Text = Val(TextBox7.Text.Trim.Split(".")(0)) + 1 & "." & 
           Val(TextBox7.Text.Trim.Split(".")(1) - 60)
        End If


        If Val(TextBox7.Text) > 24 Then

            TextBox7.Text = Format(Val(TextBox7.Text - 24), "##.##") &  " " &
            DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1, xDate)

        End If
```

Comment: Can I ask one last question? How can I arrange the format with 2 decimals only example 2.22.22 or ##.##.## And The output will also show the AM 3/3/32014 or the date format.

Comment: Still the same output sir.

Comment: Sir its still error this is the result: TextBox6.Text = "5.1" And time.Text = "3.54.1" And the output of these two is TextBox7.Text  = "8.640.1"........ I want to make it 8.64 only. thats the expected result.

Comment: Example input 1 is = 5.1 and input 2 is = 3.51.1 which is add(+) operation, and the result will be 8.640.1 which is correct but I want to round off the middle character, and the result should be 8.64.1 only no more other numbers the next number should been round off.

Comment: I already tried your first suggested code, but it is still the same result.

Comment: Sir can I disturb you again? because my client is over demanding and they pointing my project now as an urgent

Comment: TextBox7.Text = Format(Val(TextBox6.Text) + Val(Strings.Left(time.Text.Trim, 4)), "##.##") & Strings.Right(time.Text.Trim, 11) This is the last code that you gaven to me which is now correct and running the sample output of this is 8.63, now the concern is, the output should be 9.3 which is a time format, when the next decimal reach the 60 it will convert it to hours.

Comment: A little bit changes in formula, here is another example 3.56 + 5.07 = 8.63 which is correct. If the last decimal reach the 60 it will add in the first character and the answer should bhe 9.03.

Comment: Im doing this additional operation for because my project is about related to time format.

Comment: @RomJoy. ok TextBox6.Text input only show like 0.00 ah or 0.00.00

Comment: 0.00 , I tried your code sir but the output is these ##.## AM 3/3/2014"

Comment: @RomJoy Check my answer. ` Format(Val(TextBox6.Text), "##.##")`

Comment: Ah ok, I tried it almost work! but i tried to add 15.59 + 5.1 The result is 20.6 The expected result should be 21.0 Just like a minutes when it comes to 60 the hours will add 1.

Comment: Its done again sir once again thank you for the help sir. I will not forget your name, your time and your help!!!.

Comment: Whats the problem with the formula? the converting of hours is correct but the mins is no. This is my test run.................... 3.56 + 16. 58 = 20.1, The output should be 20.54

Comment: change time.Text.Trim, 4) to time.Text.Trim, 5). and you give input like this 16.58 AM date, or 16.05 like this. time textbox must have first 5 digit like this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444598/how-could-i-handle-time-format-using-additional-operation

Comment: I post my question again searh please click at the link. you are the only one could help me. please help T_T

Comment: yes I tried to do that I copied your full code and try also the trim 4 but the result is these 3.56 + 16.58 = 3.56 The output should be 20.54. I think there is something wrong in condition becase I tried to debug, I found that when the mins reach the 100 it will go back to 0 and +1 to hours. It means the conditional when mns reach 60 is not working so im trying to recode your code, please help.

Comment: @RomJoy. That question put on hold so i can't post answer. and change check my edit new req that will be help you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444598/how-could-i-handle-time-format-using-additional-operation This is my problem again sir, did you check it?

Comment: Yes sir but I tried to simulate my program again, I think the problem is, the if statement is not working because when the mins reach 100 it will add +1 to hours and mins will back to 0.

Comment: ok i think i find it give time text box input like 00.00 (beacause its only have 5) @RomJoy. If its not work show you input i will again check?

Comment: Strings.Left(time.Text.Trim, 5) to Format(Strings.Left(time.Text.Trim, 5),#0.00) Try this also

Comment: Yes! Finally!!!! Im done, thanks.... Sir If you mind can you give me a clue ^_^, If I reach 24 hrs date + 1, Example 3/3/2014. When the output comes 24.## the date will be 3/4/2014. LAst promise. T_T

Comment: No changes sor in the day and the output continues to 25 it did not bacome 1 again

Comment: If Val(TextBox7.Text.Trim.Split(".")(0)) >= 24 Then
   TextBox7.Text = Val(TextBox7.Text.Trim.Split(".")(0)) - 24 & "." & Val(TextBox7.Text.Trim.Split(".")(1)) & DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1, xDate)
End If

Comment: (textbox6.text = 5.56) + (time.text = 21.43 3/18/2014 ) = (Textbox7.text = 1.39033/19/2014) My expected is (Textbox7.text = 1.39 3/19/2014)

Comment: Time textbox have AM, PM or not having ah?

Comment: `  If Val(TextBox7.Text) > 24 Then
    
                TextBox7.Text = Format(Val(TextBox7.Text - 24), "##.##") &  " " &
                DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1, xDate)
    
            End If` write this code

Comment: Is it okay If I use this code? The out put is now running good right format I add This to my code. TextBox7.Text = TextBox7.Text.Remove(TextBox7.TextLength - 12, 1)
                TextBox7.Text = TextBox7.Text.Remove(TextBox7.TextLength - 11, 1)

Comment: Im using now this code: But my problem is when it comes to month of oct, nov, dec, The format is not running right. Example for this december.  Gives me 1.211 12/19/14 should be 1.21 12/19/14. But March to sept is correct. Example March Gives me 1.21 3/19/14 which is correct.

Comment: Im using now this code:  Dim xDate As Date = Format(CDate(Strings.Right(time.Text.Trim, 11)), "MM/dd/yyyy")

                If Val(TextBox7.Text.Trim.Split(".")(0)) >= 24 Then
                    TextBox7.Text = Val(TextBox7.Text.Trim.Split(".")(0)) - 24 & "." & Val(TextBox7.Text.Trim.Split(".")(1)) & " " & DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1, xDate)
                    TextBox7.Text = TextBox7.Text.Remove(TextBox7.TextLength - 12, 1)
                    TextBox7.Text = TextBox7.Text.Remove(TextBox7.TextLength - 11, 1)
                End If

Comment: If I copy your full code its not working, but if I edited your code just like I show before its working and my only problem is the month of oct nov dec, because there is an extra character of 1.

Comment: did you give same input for nov,oct,dec date entry @RomJoy

Comment: Yes. Is there a problem here at the format? Dim xDate As Date = Format(CDate(Strings.Right(time.Text.Trim, 11)), "MM/dd/yyyy")